# Reduce size of HTML but keep it looking similar

Tags: html, optimization

I have HTML like this:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center">milk</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>blue</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">blind</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>perpetual</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center">juice</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">jungle</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">cleaner</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">tiny</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center">lemon</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">vitamin</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>unheard</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">empty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>awesome</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">pink</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">grilled</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">mirror</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>hungry</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">opening</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">darkness</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">apply</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center">burden</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>coaster</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">rocket</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">monster</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center">rolled</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">lovers</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>plug</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>jumping</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>circus</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">bird</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">doctor</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">endless</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>golden</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">mutate</td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><b>scream</b></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">chest</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There can be many, many more rows.

There's nothing wrong with how this looks. However, this page is responsible for over 60% of the bandwidth used.

Is there any way to reduce the number of characters in this HTML while keeping it looking roughly the same?

If it matters, I'm using PHP on the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other answers already cover the easier way, and explain things nicely.

My answer reduces the number of characters in the HTML down to (probably) the absolute minimum:

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apwc2/)***

**HTML**:

```
<div id="words"><i>milk</i><b>blue</b><i>blind</i><b>perpetual</b><i>juice</i><i>jungle</i><i>cleaner</i><i>tiny</i><i>lemon</i><i>vitamin</i><b>unheard</b><i>empty</i><b>awesome</b><i>pink</i><i>grilled</i><i>mirror</i><b>hungry</b><i>opening</i><i>darkness</i><i>apply</i><i>burden</i><b>coaster</b><i>rocket</i><i>monster</i><i>rolled</i><i>lovers</i><b>plug</b><b>jumping</b><b>circus</b><i>bird</i><i>doctor</i><i>endless</i><b>golden</b><i>mutate</i><b>scream</b><i>chest</i></div>
```

**Readable HTML**:

```
<div id="words">
    <i>milk</i>
    <b>blue</b>
    <i>blind</i>
    <b>perpetual</b>
    ... 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#words {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto
}
#words i, #words b {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 3px 0;
    font-style: normal
}
```

To understand this, try to think of this as the (one letter) `<b>` and `<i>` tags having been changed to act like `<div>` tags via CSS.

If you have any questions about this technique, I will try to answer them for you.

Comment: That's amazingly smaller, and it looks the same. Thanks! Thanks for the other answers people, they were helpful also.

Comment: @bmaster: While much smaller and certainly inventive, it's *completely* changed the semantics of your markup and is arguably abusing the `i` element, which is for *"...a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose..."* (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element). Semantics matter for searchability. And I'd test *thoroughly* that those floats render correctly on all of the browsers you want to support, particularly when the display area gets narrow. The characteristics of floated elements are totally different from table cells.

Answer (score 7):

With any browser released in the last 10 years (or even longer; IE6 is okay with the below), you should be able to use [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) to drop all of those `width` and `align` attributes as well as the `width`, `border`, and `cellpadding` on the table. Depending on your browser support profile, you may be able to ditch `cellspacing` as well, but the rough equivalent — CSS's `border-spacing` property — is more recent and less well-supported, so I'll leave that out below.

For the `width` and `align` on the cells, and `width` and `cellpadding` on the table:

```
selector_for_the_table {
   width: 600px;
   border: none;
}
selector_for_the_table td {
   width: 25%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 3px;
}
```

For instance, if you give the table an `id`, you can do something like this:

CSS:

```
#theTable {
   width: 600px;
   border: none;
}
#theTable td {
   width: 25%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id='theTable' cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>milk</td>
    <td><b>blue</b></td>
    <td>blind</td>
    <td><b>perpetual</b></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ojabo3/2)

...but it doesn't have to be an `id` if there's another CSS selector that can identify the table by its location in the document, etc.

**Update**: If you're using HTML5, you can also leave off the closing `</td>` and `</tr>` tags:

```
<table id='theTable' cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>milk
    <td><b>blue</b>
    <td>blind
    <td><b>perpetual</b>
  <tr>
    <td>juice
    <td>jungle
    <td>cleaner
    <td>tiny
  ...
</table>
```

...and most browsers will correctly understand that even if you're using an HTML4 doctype (or none at all); details: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags I'm not a fan of this optional end tags thing, but a lot of people are.

Comment: It just occurred to me that if you're using HTML5, you can omit the closing `</td>` tags (and most browsers will correctly interpret it if you do that now): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious fix is to use stylesheets.

in the `head` add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style.css" />
```

get rid of *every* `width`, and `align` attribute, and in style.css put:

```
td
{
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Ideally all your styles would be in the css file, this is just a simple example.