# What is the <i> tag use for?

Tags: html, css, tags

Well I know it is meant to italicize text, but I have been using firebug on Facebook and I cannot help but realize how much they use the `<i>` tags in their layout.

[image: i tag in Facebook photo layout]

For example, for the photo thumbnail gallery, Facebook uses the `<i>` tag inside a div and places a background image style for the  tag in the photo gallery. Are there more tricks/tips/uses to the  tag ?

Comment: don't think there's anything special about `i`... they're just (ab)using it, probably because it's short. you can restyle just about any tag to look however you want.

Answer (score 10):

The `i` element has not been deprecated (contrary to popular belief), but its use to strictly italicize text has been.

> The `i` element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose, such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another language, a thought, a ship name, or some other prose whose typical typographic presentation is italicized

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element).

The last time I personally used it was to markup the scientific names of plants, eg...

```
<i>Anredera cordifolia</i> (Madiera Vine)
```

#### Update

The reason Facebook may use it is because they deal with millions of concurrent requests - sending `i` down instead of `span` saves some bytes. Using it also doesn't suffer in readability too bad, as opposed to changing that class from `tagWrapper` to `a`.

If you want to see byte saving to the extreme, look at [Google's home page](http://google.com) source.

Comment: Glad you updated that link from quackit to w3.org. +1 from me

Comment: @anydb Can't beat the horse's mouth :)

Comment: And what about xhtml 4.1? I bet facebook isn't serving html5.

Comment: +1, nice answer. I agree about why Facebook uses the `<i>` element in this case - I [suggested the same type of thing here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633065/reduce-size-of-html-but-keep-it-looking-similar/4634205#4634205).

Answer (score 0):

See [Wikipedia's Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style_%28text_formatting%29). Granted, it is not the universal manual of style, but it does give you an idea of what italics are used for, and how it is different from emphasis `<em>`. While the former is used for certain special names, referring to a name as introduction, or for foreign phrases, the latter is strictly for emphasis.

As for uses outside the above mentioned, it probably is just another of those tag misuses.